# Deadlock while using boost::asio::deadline_timer in Windows dll

Tags: c++, dll, boost-asio

I am trying to use Boost-Deadlinetimer inside a DLL, which is loaded using boost::dll::shared_library. Following code-snippets are reduced to the essentials.

Example.h:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
class Example  
{  
public:  
    Class() : m_timer(m_ioService) { } 
    virtual ~Class() { }  
    //...    
private:  
    boost::asio::io_service m_ioService;  
    boost::asio::deadline_timer m_timer;
    //...
};
```

Example.cpp:

```
#include "Example.h"
#include <boost/config.hpp>
//...
extern "C" BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT Example MyExample;
Example MyExample;
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <boost/dll/Import.hpp>
//...
boost::dll::shared_library lib("Example.dll", boost::dll::load_mode::Default_mode);
//...
```

My Problem is that there is a deadlock while loading the compiled dll as long as `m_timer` is in the constructor's initialization list.

When replacing `m_timer` by a `boost::shared_ptr` and initializing that in the constructor (or a subsequent function), then there is *no* deadlock while *loading* the dll but a deadlock while *unloading* the dll.

Anyway, I cannot really use a global deadline timer object in a Windows dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has a [LoaderLock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx) which is held from the call to `LoadLibrary` until it returns.

This lock is used by the Windows system to ensure that the process remains stable, as cascaded DLLs are properly reference counted.

Globals which are created within a DLL, are constructed by `dynamic initialization` just before DllMain runs (`DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`), and destroyed just after DllMain finishes (`DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`).

When you create a DLL with a global variable, you need to follow the rules in the link, and avoid...

- Loading DLLs
- Using Locks - cause of lock-inversion
- Creating processes
- Reading the registry
- Creating/destroying threads
- using the StringType functions.

The easiest way to cope with this would be having a separate initialize function which is called after LoadLibrary, and a Uninitialize function called before the final FreeLibrary where global variables are separately initialized.